# How can I take all fields (or at least all mandatory fields) for one object?

Tags: apex, soql, fields

I need to take all mandatory FIELD NAMEs (not FIELD LABEL) so that I can create object. What are the ways to do it outside copying each FIELD NAME from Object Manager?

Comment: Do you need programmatic access to the required fields?

Comment: No. I just need to take fields once.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open the [Developer Console](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=code_dev_console.htm&type=5) window and run this snippet:

```
Map<String, Schema.SObjectField> fieldMap = Product2.sObjectType.getDescribe().fields.getMap();
Set<String> sysNAuditFields = new Set<String> {'Id',
                                                'IsActive', 
                                                'IsDeleted',
                                                'IsArchived',
                                                'CreatedDate',
                                                'CreatedById',
                                                'LastModifiedDate',
                                                'LastModifiedById',
                                                'SystemModstamp'};    
for (Schema.SObjectField f : fieldMap.values()) {
    Schema.DescribeFieldResult fieldDesc = f.getDescribe();
    if(!fieldDesc.isNillable() && !sysNAuditFields.contains(fieldDesc.getName())) {
        system.debug(fieldDesc.getName());
    }
}
```

Change ***Product2*** for the API name of whichever object you need mandatory fields for.

**Note**: This will give all mandatory fields at an object level, not those that may have been tagged as *required* on a specific page layout for the object.

**Sample log result for this query in my org**

[image]